# Purpose of (.+?) in regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

I am kinda new to this Regex thing.

When analyzing some code I frequently come across the pattern `.+?` or `(.+?)`

I can't seem to find the meaning of this pattern using my noobish deductive reasoning.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html explains it quite well

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`.` means any character (except a new line). `+` means one or more. `?` in this context mean lazy or non-greedy. That means it will try to match the absolute minimum of characters that satisfy the quantifier. Example:

```
> 'abc'.match(/.+/)
["abc"]
> 'abc'.match(/.+?/)
["a"]
> 'abc'.match(/.*/)
["abc"]
> 'abc'.match(/.*?/)
[""]
```

Answer (score 5):

It depends what kind of knowledge you have about patterns. Here's an explanation that assumes you have some kind of basic idea about what regular expressions are:

- `.` matches any character
- `+` means repeat the last pattern 1 or more times
- so far, `.+` means *one or more characters*
- `?` means **ungreedy**, which means the matching will stop with the first occasion.

A quick explanation on greediness:

```
/.+X/.exec("aaaXaaaXaaa");
["aaaXaaaX"]
/.+?X/.exec("aaaXaaaXaaa");
["aaaX"]
```

As you can see, the `?` character makes the search ungreedy, thus matching as little as possible.